# How to move my dotnetnuke project to the root folder?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have [a web site](http://coloredpencilpaintingschool.com/dotnetnuke/) in dotnetnuke.

Now I want to move all the files from the dotnetnuke folder to the root. But I don't know how it is. What are the steps that I must follow to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a total of three things you need to do.

1. Add a new portal alias to the DNN site to support the domain name only.  You can do this via "Admin" -> "Site Settings" when logged in as a host user.
2. You will need to then copy all of the files from the /dotnetnuke folder to the root
3. You might need to modify text/html module instances to correct any links to images that might include the /dotnetnuke folder within the URL.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the domain up in IIS.  All sites/portals must point to the same folder in IIS.  Always the root folder for DotNetNuke.  Mine for example is: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DotNetNuke\
   This means that www.domain.com and www.domain2.com (and any other) point to the same physical folder in IIS. (Provided you your DNS is already pointing to your server here)
2. Create a 2nd alias for your existing portal.

   - Log In as Host and go to Host/Portals
   - Click on Edit (pencil) next to your existing portal.
   - In the Advanced Settings, expand Portal Aliases
   - Click on 'Add a new Alias
   - Enter your domain in the text box and save your changes.

No need to move any files.

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting to point the whole site into the dotnetnuke section you need to change the root folder on IIS  to the dotnetnuke one.